# Good idea to use SQS to move thousands of databases?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

We want to move from using MySQL on an EC2 instance to RDS and setup replication. Seems like a no-brainer, right? Well, I've got 30,000 databases to move (don't ask). While setting up replication seems to work well, the process of getting the 30,000 databases into RDS is a royal pain; it takes forever and something almost alway happens.

The nightly backup takes about two hours. I end up with a multi-GB SQL dump file. When I try to restore it, something almost always goes wrong: the RDS instance wasn't big enough memory-wise and crashed, the localhost ran out of swap space, the network connection went flaky. Whatever! I did get it to restore once; IIRC it took 23 hours (30K MySQL DBs are a ton of file IO).

So today, I decided to use mydumper. It generated 30,000 schema files for the database in about two hours, then suddenly, the source MySQL went into uninterruptible sleep according to top, I lost my client connections, strace showed it was still trying to read files, and the mydumper process crashed. I restarted the whole process and just checked the status; mysqld restarted  2.5 hours into it for some reason.

So here's what I'm thinking and I'd like your input: I write two python scripts: firstScript.py will run mydumper on a single database, update a status table, package up the SQL, put it onto an AWS SQS queue, repeating until no more databases are found; the secondScript.py reads from the queue, runs the SQL and updates the status table, repeating until no more messages are found.

I *think* this can work. Do you? The main thing I'm not sure of is this: can I simply run multiple secondScript.py by Ctrl-Z-ing them into the background?

Or does someone have a better way of moving 30,000 databases?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use mysqldump or mydumper to make a logical dump. Loading the resulting SQL-format dump takes too long.

Instead, use Percona XtraBackup to make a physical backup of your EC2 instance, and upload the backup to S3. Then restore to the RDS instance from S3, setup replication on the RDS instance to your EC2 instance, and let it catch up.

The feature of restoring a physical MySQL backup to RDS was announced in November 2017.

See also:

- https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/04/02/migrate-to-amazon-rds-with-percona-xtrabackup/
- https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/easily-restore-an-amazon-rds-mysql-database-from-your-mysql-backup/

You should try it out with a smaller instance than your 30k databases just so you get some practice with the steps. See the steps in the Percona blog I linked to above.

Comment: I did look at Percona's XtraBackup. (I love their toolkit!) The drawbacks I found were 1) it makes a list of databases to backup before doing anything and what program can handle a 30K long list of arguments? and 2) we're still (still!) on MySQL 5.5. :-(  (One of my jobs at this company is drag them, kicking and screaming, into the technology of 2010 at least.)